# Rest service with StreamingResponseBody fails after a few seconds

Tags: rest, spring-boot, asynchronous

When I call a service that response **StreamingResponseBody**, download starts and downloads some MBs but after some time, it stops and this is what gets shown on my console:

```
2019-07-26 09:52:39.263 ERROR 3924 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter     : Exception while processing an asynchronous request
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Calling [asyncError()] is not valid for a request with Async state [MUST_DISPATCH]
    at org.apache.coyote.AsyncStateMachine.asyncError(AsyncStateMachine.java:440) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.action(AbstractProcessor.java:512) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.coyote.Request.action(Request.java:430) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.AsyncContextImpl.setErrorState(AsyncContextImpl.java:401) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.asyncDispatch(CoyoteAdapter.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.dispatch(AbstractProcessor.java:241) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:836) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1747) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

Debugging I could see that the most internal exception is: java.io.IOException: The current thread was interrupted.

**The service code:**

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class MyController { 

    @GetMapping("/srbFile")
    public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> srbFile() {
        StreamingResponseBody srb = (out) -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
                try {
                    String msg = String.valueOf(i);
                    out.write(("Hello Every body: " + msg + System.lineSeparator()).getBytes());
                    out.flush();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        return ResponseEntity.ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=data.csv").body(srb);
    }
}
```

**In the client side:**

A simple link: `<a href="/srbFile">Download</a>`

**Environment:**

Spring Boot 2.1.5.RELEASE
Java: OpenJdk 11.0.1

Thanks for Advance!